# Python: Add to Include Path on the Command Line

Tags: python, unit-testing, include, include-path

Is there a way to add include paths to python on the command line?  What I am trying to do is run a unit test that uses a some code in a lib directory:

$ python -I lib/ test/my-test.py

but this fails.  I can append to my path in my-test.py but that seems less than optimal since its path dependent.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables):

```
PYTHONPATH=lib/ python test/my-test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a command line switch for this, but you can just set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the lib directory:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/lib/ python test/my-test.py
```